# LS_COLORS failing to source in .zshrc

Tags: command-line, zsh

I've noticed a strange problem with sourcing.

```
source /etc/zsh/zshrc in .zshrc fails to set LS_COLORS
```

The last line in `/etc/zsh/zshrc`:

```
eval $(dircolors /etc/zsh/DIR_COLORS)
```

But it has no effect.

I've tried adding the line directly into `.zshrc` as well but still no success.

Only when I execute from the command line:

```
eval $(dircolors /etc/zsh/DIR_COLORS)
```

it does work as expected.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?